# One login for every site

Tags: feature-request, login, linked-accounts

There should be one login for every site on Stack Exchange. I have to login each time I go to a different site, for instance from *[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)* to *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)* (ELL).

For example, on Google's websites if a user logs in on one site, say Gmail, then if he goes to Google+ or YouTube, he does not need to enter his credentials again to log in.

But here we have to give credentials each time on a different site.

I request a similar feature, for the ease of users.

I get the cookie thing that if you have already logged in then you don't need to log in again when you come back to the site.

But what I want is that on each site where the user is registered, say Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow and English Language & Usage, he should be able to use them all in flow once he is logged in anyone of them.